# InnoDB Buffer Pool Hit Rate

Tags: mysql, innodb, buffer-pool

As given at http://cherry.world.edoors.com/COBFKUqnUdBY one can obtain buffer hit ratio by following sql query:

```
SELECT round ((P2.variable_value / P1.variable_value),4), 
P2.variable_value, P1.variable_value
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P1,
information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P2
WHERE P1. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads';
```

## QUESTIONS

- From what period are buffer hit ratio given by that query? From start of database engine till now?
- Is there possibility to obtain buffer hit ratio from given period of time? (for example: last 10 minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the Hit Rate since [Uptime (Last MySQL Startup)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Uptime)

There are two things you can do to get the Last 10 Minutes

## METHOD #1

Flush all Status Values, Sleep 10 min, Run Query

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT SLEEP(600) INTO @x;
SELECT round ((P2.variable_value / P1.variable_value),4), 
P2.variable_value, P1.variable_value
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P1,
information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P2
WHERE P1. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads';
```

## METHOD #2

Capture [innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests), [innodb_buffer_pool_reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_reads), Sleep 10 minutes, Run Query with Differences in innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests and innodb_buffer_pool_reads

```
SELECT
    P1.variable_value,P2.variable_value
INTO
    @rqs,@rds
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P1,
information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P2
WHERE P1.variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2.variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads'; 
SELECT SLEEP(600) INTO @x;
SELECT round (((P2.variable_value - @rds) / (P1.variable_value - @rqs)),4), 
P2.variable_value, P1.variable_value
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P1,
information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P2
WHERE P1.variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2.variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads';
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I would suggest 2% (0.02) is a reasonable upper limit on the ratio.

Comment: Isn't Method #1 telling the Miss Rate? I thought Hit Rate was: Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests / (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests + Innodb_buffer_pool_reads) * 100
http://www.fromdual.com/innodb-variables-and-status-explained

Comment: Since Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests are all logical reads and Innodb_buffer_pool_reads are logical reads that could not be satisfied by the buffer pool and read from disk, hit rate should be (Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests - Innodb_buffer_pool_reads) / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests * 100. I'll post a seperate answer for the SQLs.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLs from RolandoMySQLDBA calculates the buffer pool miss rate.
To calculate the hit rate (in percentage) you need to use the following formula

`(Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests - Innodb_buffer_pool_reads) / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests * 100`

(Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests are all logical reads and Innodb_buffer_pool_reads are logical reads that could not be satisfied by the buffer pool and read from disk as explained [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests))

The SQLs are therefore for 5.7:

```
SELECT round ((P1.variable_value - P2.variable_value) / P1.variable_value  * 100,4) 'Hit Rate in %', 
P2.variable_value 'Physical BP Reads', P1.variable_value 'All BP Reads'
FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P1,
information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS P2
WHERE P1. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads';
```

and for 8.0:

```
SELECT round ((P1.variable_value - P2.variable_value) / P1.variable_value * 100,4) 'Hit Rate in %', 
P2.variable_value 'Physical BP Reads', P1.variable_value 'All BP Reads'
FROM performance_schema.global_status P1,
performance_schema.global_status P2
WHERE P1. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests'
AND P2. variable_name = 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads';
```

Also, `FLUSH STATUS` does no longer reset those two counters (tested in MySQL 8.0).

Comment: It must be pointed out that the original question asks for Hit Ratio not Hit Rate (which is a percentage). My mistake in my answer was not using the word Ratio, Note how the comment from Rick James coincides with Ratio. A ratio of innodb_buffer_pool_reads / innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests being 0.02 means 1 read from disk for every 50 reads requests. Your answer is expressing 98% (49 reads requests out of 50 not needing to read from disk). Nothing wrong with your answer from that perspective so +1 for you. So a ratio above 0.02 would be bad. This is also the Miss Rate as you mentioned